# How do you get a specfic part of a word in a file using awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a script which goes like this: 
script.m

```
    rng('shuffle');
    load samples123/stage17/resamp_stage.mat
    indarray = str2num(getenv('arrayindex')); 
    index = (indarray-1)*4+1:(indarray)*4
    samplenow = samplestage(index,:);

    for i = 1:4 
       ind = index(i); 
       i 
       num = 123;
       sampleind = samplenow(i,:);
       opt.Ndrag = 1; 
       a = cputime; 
       outsmpl = continue_dragon(opt,beta,sampleind,stage,num,covsmpl,ind); 
       b = cputime; 
       b-a
       toc 
    end
```

I would like to retrieve only 'stage17', which is in the second line. I tried the following:

```
  awk '/samples123/{print $2}' script.m
```

But this gives out : samples123/stage17/resamp_stage.mat

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`perl` has better capture groups support than `awk`, and is arguably more suited for this task.

```
perl -lane 'print $1 if /\/(.*)\//' script.m
stage17

perl -lane 'print $1 if /\/[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\//' script.m
17
```

The same can be accomplished with `awk`, however, by employing `gensub`:

```
awk '/\/.*\// {a=gensub(/.*\/(.*)\/.*/,"\\1","g"); print a}' script.m
stage17

awk '/\/.*\// {a=gensub(/.*\/[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^0-9]*\/.*/,"\\1","g"); print a}' script.m
17
```

Since you don't specify what the search criteria should be, I assumed it's a line containing two forward slashes; it could be the second line, a line starting with `load`, or a line containing `samples123` as your `awk` code would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use `sed` and `awk` to solve it at the same time.

If keyword is `samples123`, then command is

```
awk 'match($0,/samples123/){print gensub(/.*\/([^\/]*)\/.*/,"\\1","g",$0)}' script.m

sed -r -n '/samples123/{s@.*\/([^\/]*)\/.*@\1@g;p}' script.m
```

If has no keyword, just via two slash `/`, then command is

```
awk 'match($0,/\/[^\/]*\//){print gensub(/.*\/([^\/]*)\/.*/,"\\1","g",$0)}' script.m

sed -r -n '/\/[^\/]*\//{s@.*\/([^\/]*)\/.*@\1@g;p}' script.m
```